# How to configure ErpNext docker hub image on Plesk Obsidian docker extension settings?

Tags: docker, settings, plesk, dockerhub

Greetings to our community. It might be a bit of noob question.
I came across to use Plesk docker extension to run production version of the ErpNext instance.
Note: VPS with Plesk installed i only have and other options are not available...!!!

I have found tutorial on youtube that it's more likely possible to get app running using Plesk docker extension with  docker image taken from docker hub . I have found. the docker image and pulled it here is a pic
[image]

What i need to do with all volumes and environment variables to configure this image to have it up and running.

when i press start on panel getting [image]

This kind of activity i have concerns about the message volumes not mounted etc.
So my questions are:

1. What should i do in settings to have the mounted volumes?
2. How to configure proxy on Plesk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution!!!

I have followed docker installation documentation and this was helpful
On the GitHub - frappe/frappe_docker: Docker images for production and development setups of the Frappe framework and ERPNext

I Got what you need. there is a file example.env - can be renamed to your .env and edited as your needs are (i have added website url and my email in file (command - cp example.env .env then nano .env))
pwd.yml file renamed to docker-compose.yml file and edited ports for proxy .
After that
docker-compose up -d command and all containers got up and are visible in Plesk panel.
in Plesk webspace I have configured the proxy port to the port i have provided in docker-compose.yml file all containers are visible images downloaded and ERPNext ready to be configured and used for it purpose.

I am Happy!!!